# position relative in css without top and right mention

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

```
.classname {
       position: relative;
}
```

position relative in css without top right left and bottom  mention,

I read that this not change any position, but in some web page write position: relative; without top right left bottom mention and if I delete "position: relative;" then position will change.
Can I know what exact use of "position: relative; " without top right left and bottom mention.

Comment: any div with position relative have no effect when adding top right bottom.

Comment: Can you reproduce the result here in a fiddle, we can tell then the reason of the outcome.

Answer (score 4):

This type of positioning is probably the most confusing and misused. What it really means is "relative to itself". If you set **position: relative;** on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as position: static; But if you DO give it some other positioning attribute, say, **top: 10px;**, it will shift it's position 10 pixels DOWN from where it would NORMALLY be. I'm sure you can imagine, the ability to shift an element around based on it's regular position is pretty useful. I find myself using this to line up form elements many times that have a tendency to not want to line up how I want them to.

There are two other things that happen when you set position: relative; on an element that you should be aware of. One is that it introduces the ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with statically positioned elements. Even if you don't set a z-index value, this element will now appear on top of any other statically positioned element. You can't fight it by setting a higher z-index value on a statically positioned element. The other thing that happens is **it limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements.** Any element that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block.

Comment: On the final line...it would be more accurate to say *"Any absolutely positioned element that is a child (or descendant) of the relatively positioned element can be positioned **in relation to** that 'parent' element"*.

Answer (score 0):

The most known use for setting position relative on a parent element is to position child elements, set to position absolute, relative to the parents position.